# Android, Phonegap, Jquery mobile textarea issue

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

When focusing into textarea which contains letters(with numbers it`s working fine) from another input field, some strange behaviors happen.

On some android versions it crashes, on some versions last 2 text letters just deletes... on some also previous input text duplicates under text area(see picture).

Also when focusing in -> on short time previous focused in input field value is shown in textarea. Strange is that on older android version it works fine.

**You can create a static counter and increment it each time**
Tried to remove 100% width, but didn't help ([Android 100% width issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/3835))

[image]

Comment: "You can create a static counter and increment it each time" -> not quite sure what you mean with that..but each text input has unique id.

Answer (score 0):

Finally we came up with that when switching between type="number" and type="text" fields, somehow number validation was performed to text field and it went wrong.
So we changed type="number" to type text, and validating it manually now.. 
Probably some cordova or jquery mobile bug.